# ImportTestContainers caused exception on Github Actions

Tags: spring-boot, testcontainers

I tried to adopt the new spring boot testcontainers feature in my project, but all tests used `@ImportTestcontaienrs` failed.

I created a Kotlin interface to declare containers.

```kotlin
interface ContainersConfig{

   companion object{ 
       @Container
       @ServiceConnction
       var postgresSQLContaienr...
   }
}
```

And applied the config on test classes by `@ImportTestcontainers`.

**When running the test classes one by one on my local machine, all are passed.**

But when I pushed the codes to Github and build the project on Github actions.

I got the exceptions like this.

```bash
      Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'r2dbcScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/R2dbcInitializationConfiguration.class]: 
Failed to execute database script

      Caused by: org.springframework.r2dbc.connection.init.UncategorizedScriptException: 
Failed to execute database script

      Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: 
Failed to obtain R2DBC Connection

      Caused by: io.r2dbc.postgresql.ExceptionFactory$PostgresqlNonTransientResourceException: 
[53300] sorry, too many clients already
```

All test classes used `@ImportTestContainers` are failed with similar info.

Comment: which example should I take a look? :)

Comment: @EddúMeléndez No example project for this, I have just tried to convert my real project to use the new feature of Spring boot 3.1, it is about 40 tests used testcontainers Postgres.

Comment: do you have a pool connection? are tests parallelized? My guess is that the same container instance is being used for multiple tests and each test is creating a connection pool in its own context

Comment: Spring Boot configure r2dbc-pool automatically. My original solution is using a custom `ApplicationContextInitializer` like this, https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/blob/master/testcontainers/src/test/java/com/example/demo/PostRepositoryWithCustomContextInitializerTest.java, (use a shared standalone class in my real project) , configured it in the `@ContextConfiguration`  annotation.